# Why is this for loop giving this output?

Tags: java, for-loop

Why is the output of the following code: 13 15 17

I think it should be: 15 17 19

[image: here is my explanation]

Here's the code:

```
package com.example.barker;
class dog {
}

public class Bark {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Bark o = new Bark();
        o.go();
    }

    void go(){
        int y =7;
        for(int x = 1; x<8; x++) {
            y++;
            if(x>4) {
                System.out.print(++y + " ");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: x=1,y=8 --> x=4,y=11 then x = 5, y =13; x = 6, y =15; x = 6, y =17

Comment: Your `y` is incremented 4 times before entering into the `if condition` and then once before printing with `++`. All looks good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the Anwer is right.

I will Explain the working of the code to get understand.

First

> y=7
>
> x=0

and after first iteration

> y=8 (y++;) and x=1 (int x = 1;) (not printing because x not greater then 4)

after Second Iteration

> y=9 (y++;) and x=2 (x++;) (not printing because x not greater then 4)

after Third Iteration

> y=10 (y++;) and x=3 (x++;) (not printing because x not greater then 4)

after Fourth Iteration

> y=11 (y++;) and x=4 (x++;) (not printing because x not greater then 4)

after Fifth Iteration

> y=12 (y++;) and x=5 (x++;)
>
> Now x is greater than 4 and going to **System.out.print(++y + " ");**

Here you are writing ++y ,means pre-increment

> ie, increment y and printing
>
> ie, y=13 and x=6 printing(13)

After next Iteration

> y=14(y++;) and before printing the value of **y** doing ++y 
>   ie,
>   y=15 (++y;)  printing(15)

After next Iteration

> y=16(y++;) and before printing the value of **y** doing ++y 
>   ie,
>   y=17 (++y;) printing(17)

So the Output is **13 15 17**

Thanks and happy coding.

Answer (score 1):

Change the conditions like below, to get your desired result.

```js
for(int x = 1; x<10; x++) {
            y++;
            if(x>6) {
                System.out.print(++y + " ");
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's first understand the operations happening within the for loop:

- y++ will perform the +1 operation after the line of code finishes executing
- ++y will first perform the +1 operation and then execute the rest of the line of code

Now, let's look at the for loop:

```
for(int x = 1; x<8; x++) {
        y++;
        if(x>4) {
            System.out.print(++y + " ");
        }
    }
```

For each iteration, we will look at the values for x and y:

x = 1, y = 7 (start of first iteration)

x = 1, y = 8 (end of iteration)

x = 2, y = 8 (start of first iteration)

x = 2, y = 9 (end of iteration)

x = 3, y = 9 (start of first iteration)

x = 3, y = 10 (end of iteration)

x = 4, y = 10 (start of first iteration)

x = 4, y = 11 (end of iteration)

x = 5, y = 11 (start of first iteration)

x = 5, y = 12 (y++ line)

x = 5, y = 13 (x > 4, and because of that, ++y executes)

---

The logic has become pretty apparent, but you can continue to debug this yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps.
Here, goes the explanation :

```
y=7 //At Start
```

When you enter in the loop:

```
x = 1 and y = 8
x = 2 and y = 9
x= 3 and y = 10
x = 4 and y = 11
x = 5 // which makes the if condition true
```

y will become 12 and when it goes into if `System.out.print(++y + " ")`
It will first increment then prints.
So, it will print `y = 13`.

Similarly, when x = 6 y will be 14 and in if it becomes 15 and so on.